# Suppress console output during RSpec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing the class which put on the console some messages (with puts, p warnings and etc.).  I am just wondering if there is any ability to suppress this output during RSpec tests ?

Comment: Architecturally, you may be better off using a logging library or somehow encapsulating the print statements, so that you can toggle printing from some global config. It wouldn't be too hard to search & replace with sed all `print`, `p`, etc. with `Your::Logger.warn` or something.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I suppress `puts` output in my classes by redirecting `$stout` to a text file. That way, if I need to see the output for any reason, it is there but it doesn't muddy up my test results.

```
#spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all, &:silence_output)
  config.after(:all,  &:enable_output)
end

public
# Redirects stderr and stout to /dev/null.txt
def silence_output
  # Store the original stderr and stdout in order to restore them later
  @original_stderr = $stderr
  @original_stdout = $stdout

  # Redirect stderr and stdout
  $stderr = File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'dev', 'null.txt'), 'w')
  $stdout = File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'dev', 'null.txt'), 'w')
end

# Replace stderr and stdout so anything else is output correctly
def enable_output
  $stderr = @original_stderr
  $stdout = @original_stdout
  @original_stderr = nil
  @original_stdout = nil
end
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment by @MyronMarston, it probably would be smarter to just insert the methods directly into `before` and `after` as blocks.

```
#spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  original_stderr = $stderr
  original_stdout = $stdout
  config.before(:all) do 
    # Redirect stderr and stdout
    $stderr = File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'dev', 'null.txt'), 'w')
    $stdout = File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'dev', 'null.txt'), 'w')
  end
  config.after(:all) do 
    $stderr = original_stderr
    $stdout = original_stdout
  end
end
```

It looks a little cleaner and keeps methods off of `main`. 
Also, note that if you are using Ruby 2.0, you can use `__dir__` instead of `File.dirname(__FILE__)`.

**EDIT2**

Also it should be mentioned, that you can forward to true os `/dev/null` by using `File::NULL` as it was introduced in Ruby v 1.9.3. (jruby 1.7)

Then the code snippet will look as following:

```
#spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  original_stderr = $stderr
  original_stdout = $stdout
  config.before(:all) do
    # Redirect stderr and stdout
    $stderr = File.open(File::NULL, "w")
    $stdout = File.open(File::NULL, "w")
  end
  config.after(:all) do
    $stderr = original_stderr
    $stdout = original_stdout
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, but bear in mind that it adds `silence_output` and `enable_output` to every object in the system.  I think it's fine to do so in small one-off scripts, but otherwise I avoid defining methods on `main`.

Comment: @MyronMarston You are right. Though it may not cause problems since it is only meant to be used in RSpec tests, it would be smarter to keep them off of `main`. I added to my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This didn't work for me perfectly. It suppressed some output but not all. I wrote some "puts" within the blocks and they got called several times!

Comment: @hammady That's odd.  I can't think of any reason off the top of my head why it would only capture some of the standard out but not all. I'll try to see if I can duplicate your issue later when I have access to a computer. Let me know if you find out why before then.

Comment: I am using [rjb](https://github.com/arton/rjb) to bind to Java API and sometimes it generates output, could be that rjb overrides $stdout to STDOUT at some point, will check this

Comment: Another tip: I use this redirection not in global hooks, but in shared context "mute sterror and stout", with `before(:each) {}` and `after(:each) {}` - in my setup (rspec 3.2) it supresses the output of example while keeping other (more useful in my case) output of a rspec.

Comment: This solution doesn't get rid of the "Non US-ASCII detected and no charset defined." output

Comment: For me this didn't work in a plain ruby project. Simply overriding `$stdout` (same for `$stderr`) didn't work. I had to use `reopen`, as e.g. `$stdout.reopen File.new('/dev/null', 'w')`

Comment: I just discovered with RSpec's new `expect { <code with output> }.to output(..).to_stdout` you don't need to redirect output anymore, RSpec will actually capture it and not output! See: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher

Comment: *****PLEASE NOTE***** If you use pry, I have found this setup to swallow pry output to the console. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: instead of saving the input and output, you can reset to the default: `$stdout = STDOUT`.

Answer (score 31):

An Rspec3.0 Version would be => in spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before { allow($stdout).to receive(:puts) }
end
```

it will act as `before(:each)`

but :each is default, so no need to write it explicitly

Comment: stubbing `:write` rather than `:puts` worked for me.

Comment: `allow($stdout).to receive(:puts)` (or `:write`) should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 30):

Try stubbing methods that make the output in a before block, e.g.

```
before do
  IO.any_instance.stub(:puts) # globally
  YourClass.any_instance.stub(:puts) # or for just one class
end
```

This is explicit, so you won't miss anything you don't want to miss. If you don't care about any output and the method above doesn't work you can always stub the IO object itself:

```
before do
  $stdout.stub(:write) # and/or $stderr if needed
end
```

Comment: so simple to just stub out `$stdout` on the tests that I know will write and I don't want them to, thanks :)

Answer (score 19):

**Tested with rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)**

In describe block you could do

```
# spec_helper.rb
def suppress_log_output
  allow(STDOUT).to receive(:puts) # this disables puts
  logger = double('Logger').as_null_object
  allow(Logger).to receive(:new).and_return(logger)
end

# some_class_spec.rb
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  before do
    suppress_log_output
  end
end
```

This way you have the advantage of toggling log output for specific tests. Note, this **will not** suppress rspec warnings, or messages from rspec.

Another way to disable warnings coming from gems:

add `config.warnings = false` to spec_helper

If you wanted to suppress only certain logger methods, like `error, info, or warn` you could do

`allow_any_instance_of(Logger).to receive(:warn).and_return(nil)`

To disable warnings coming from the rspec gem

`allow(RSpec::Support).to receive(:warning_notifier).and_return(nil)`

but this is generally discouraged because it is meant as a way to let you know you are doing something smelly in your tests.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to suppress output for a single test, there is a more concise way:

> ```
> it "should do something with printing" do
>   silence_stream(STDOUT) do
>     foo.print.should be_true
>   end
> end
> ```

You may want to change `STDOUT` to `STDERR` if your test prints an error.

Comment: I wanted to note that [silence_stream](http://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/silence_stream) is a part of [activesupport](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport).

Comment: [silence_stream is now deprecated](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.2.0/Kernel:silence_stream)

Answer (score 9):

After trying all of these examples, I ended up using this varation which **does not silence or mute binding.pry**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    allow($stdout).to receive(:puts)
    allow($stdout).to receive(:write)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the only solution on this thread that worked for me. And only the stub on `write` was necessary for me.

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer for Rails 5, in a one-off situation:

```
before do
  RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope do
    allow(STDOUT).to receive(:puts)
  end
end
```

You can make this into a method in spec_helper if you'll be doing this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to inject an IO object defaulting to STDOUT. This also makes it easier to assert on the output if you want to.

E.g.

```
def my_method(arg, io: STDOUT)
  io.puts "hello"
  arg.reverse
end
```

And then in your test:

```
# Suppress it.

my_method("hi", io: StringIO.new)

# Assert on it.

io = StringIO.new
my_method("hi", io: io)

output = io.tap(&:rewind).read
expect(output).to include("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the object itself supress based on the environment:

```
class Foo
  def call
    puts("blah blah")
    # ...
  end

  private
  
  def puts(msg)
    return if ENV['APP_ENV'] == 'test'
    super
  end
end
```