# Does creating message expectations in RSpec get rid of residual messages from test passing on the console?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my class, I have a method. In the else block, it puts out a message "A number you typed isn't even on the card..." and a copy of the card.

```
def is_input_valid?(input)
   if current_card.include?(input.first) && current_card.include?(input.last) 
      true
   else 
      puts "A number you typed isn't even on the card..."
      p current_card
      false
   end
end
```

In my test, I purposely make the method go to the else block and it passes.

```
it "returns false if input contains ANY numbers NOT from the current_card" do
   allow(deck).to receive(:gets) {"99/99"}
   deck.get_player_input

   expect(deck.is_input_valid?(deck.player_input)).to be(false)
end
```

On my console, I get this:

```
...............A number you typed isn't even on the card...
[6, 6, 6, 6]
.

Finished in 0.026 seconds (files took 0.62704 seconds to load)
16 examples, 0 failures
```

The test passes but I don't want to see the bit. How do I get rid of it?

```
...............A number you typed isn't even on the card...
    [6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: That's because `p` and `rspec` both go to `STDOUT`.  That's merely a side effect of using a print statement.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I can move it to a imperative shell which I don't test but that would take some work.

Comment: Consider that SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430551/suppress-console-output-during-rspec-tests

Comment: `is_input_valid` is a java convention, use `input_valid?` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to silence the `STDOUT` stream in the test locally, 
in spec_helper.rb

```
def suppress_output
  allow(STDOUT).to receive(:puts) # this disables puts
end
```

in the test

```
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  before do
    suppress_output
  end
end
```

if you are using Rails, use [silence_stream](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/Kernel/silence_stream).

```
it "returns false if input contains ANY numbers NOT from the current_card" do
  allow(deck).to receive(:gets) {"99/99"}
  silence_stream(STDOUT) do
     deck.get_player_input
     expect(deck.is_input_valid?(deck.player_input)).to be(false)
  end
end
```

Or globally (Rspec 3+)

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before { allow($stdout).to receive(:puts) }
end
```

Comment: Is this only for rails?  `NoMethodError:
       undefined method `silence_stream' for #<Deck:0x34e87c0>`

Comment: @KaMok Yes, updated the answer with generic solution