# how to test program without running it [ruby test/unit]

Tags: ruby

I have some code like this

```
def something(x)
  x = x * 1
end

puts "something"
```

and i want to make tests to this code

```
require 'something.rb'
require 'test/unit'

class StringTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_something
    assert_equal(1, something(1))
  end
end
```

it works, but i have output from all instructions from file (i see "something" before tests)
how can i test only methods in my code, without running all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `require` a file, you literally *are* "running it". That is how your test knows that `something` method is defined - because it has already initialised the definition.

What you are really asking, I suppose, is how to silence the `puts` command(s) when `require`ing the file. There are several possible approaches for this - here are some suggestions:

Don't use `puts`, directly. One really crude but simple approach could be to wrap these debug messages a helper method - such as:

```
# something.rb:

def debug(message)
  unless $debug_messages_disabled
    puts message
  end
end

def something(x)
  x = x * 1
end

debug "something"


# in your spec (spec_helper.rb?):
$debug_messages_disabled = true
```

However, this approach does not scale well at all...

A better approach could be to [use a `Logger`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) instead of `puts`. If you choose to log to a file, then your problem is already solved! And, if you insist on logging to `stdout`, then you could simply increase the log level when running the tests - so long as you have a convenient way to set this log level. Something like:

```
# something.rb:
# ...
MyApplication.logger.debug "something" # NOT `puts`

# config/environments/development.rb
config.log_level = :debug

# config/environments/test.rb
config.log_level = :warn
```

...But that sort of approach probably way too much effort to set up for a single-file like this!

Which leads to the final, easy option to hide the output of those `puts` commands: [Suppress the STDOUT in your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15430551/1954610).

You could either achieve this by *only* stubbing `puts` commands:

```
# spec_helper.rb
before do
  IO.any_instance.stub(:puts) # globally
  YourClass.any_instance.stub(:puts) # or for just one class
end
```

Or, for an even more general solution, you can block *all* STDOUT:

```
#spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  original_stderr = $stderr
  original_stdout = $stdout
  config.before(:all) do
    # Redirect stderr and stdout
    $stderr = File.open(File::NULL, "w")
    $stdout = File.open(File::NULL, "w")
  end
  config.after(:all) do
    $stderr = original_stderr
    $stdout = original_stdout
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code is written now, there is no easy way to run the `something` method without first requiring or loading the file it is contained in, which causes your `puts` command to be executed.

My main recommendation would be to refactor the Ruby file you have.  You could move the `puts` statement in to a method so that it does not get run automatically.  Most Ruby libraries are written this way: the files in the library will not have any externally-visible side effects when loaded; they just define methods, classes, and modules.

If refactoring is not an option for some reason, you could use a hack like this to prevent the output from getting printed, but it probably won't work on Windows since it lacks good POSIX support:

```
require 'fcntl'

puts "this gets printed"

# Duplicate the stdout file descriptor and then change the original
# one to be a black hole.
stdout_copy_fd = $stdout.fcntl(Fcntl::F_DUPFD)
$stdout.reopen("/dev/null", "w")

puts "this is blocked"
# you can require/load your noisy Ruby scripts here

# Restore the stdout file descriptor.
$stdout.reopen IO.new(stdout_copy_fd)

puts "this gets printed too"
```

Answer (score 1):

To restate the question as I see it: *"I have a ruby file that defines methods and runs other commands. How can I test the methods without running the commands?"*

If your script's commands are solely for output - `puts`, logging, debugging, `stdout` or `stderr`, etc. - then the other answers here are more than sufficient.

But what if your commands are doing other stuff like setting default values or performing valid load-time work? Or maybe your file is designed to be run as a standalone script and/or required by other files?

**Solution #1: Consider Refactoring**

The first question to ask is whether or not it makes sense to refactor your code. Are there any non-method commands (or series of commands) that would be useful to include in some other file? Are you interested in running unit tests against the non-method commands? If the answer to either is "yes", you'll be better served by wrapping your standalone commands in a method.

```
# other methods

def run_something
  # do stuff
end

run_something
```

Generally, it is good practice to keep your executables as small as possible and keep them separate from your class and method definitions (small `bin`, big `lib`). Extending the above example, you'd have something like this:

In `lib/something.rb`:

```
# other methods

def run_something
  # do stuff
end
```

In `bin/something.rb`:

```
require_relative '../lib/something.rb'

run_something
```

**Solution #2: Conditional Execution**

Whenever a file is run or loaded/required, all commands in the file are immediately executed. It makes no difference whether those commands are class/method definitions or standalone commands. If you have any standalone commands that should be executed when the file is run directly (e.g. `ruby something.rb`) but not executed when loaded by another file (e.g. `require 'something.rb'`), you can test for this condition like so:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  run_something
end
```

`__FILE__` is a magic value, documented at [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__) as follows:

> The name of the file currently being executed, including path relative
>   to the directory where the application was started up (or the current
>   directory, if it has been changed). The current file is, in some
>   cases, different from the startup file for the running application,
>   which is available in the global variable $0.

`$0` and `$PROGRAM_NAME` are both global variables and can be used interchangeably (one is an alias of the other).

So the expression `if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME` translates to "if the current file is the startup file."